# Having trouble with rigging fingers

Tags: rigging

The model I started with had its hands connected to its thighs. I tried rigging the hands but they took part of the thigh with it. I figured out not to rig the hands but just the arms and that worked perfect.

Now I want to rig the hands. As soon as I do that I can't control the first rig I added in the rest of the body. Anyone have a fix for this issue? Can you control two different rigs on one object?

Comment: Consider uploading your blend file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Also it's possible to join two rigs together by selecting both and pressing Cmd+J